# streaming radio on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio-streaming, internet-radio

i would like to know if is it possible to read a radio stream from a RSS feed on a WP device and while using C# language.
ty

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but it depends on the format of the stream you will be obtaining. The RSS feed by itself contains no streaming data whatsoever, other than the location of the actual media. You might need to use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to get the data and implement [MediaStreamSource](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/10/01/mediastreamsource-sample-with-source-code.aspx) to actually process the streamed content.